# Tuples OPL in VRP

Tags: cplex, constraint, vehicle-routing, opl

I am trying to build a constraint of the form `x[i j] +x[j i] <y[i][j]` where `x` is a decision variable if arc `ij` is used.

The arcs are defined in terms of tuples. However, not all arcs are available in that `[2 3]` is presented while `[3 2]` is not.

`y[i][j]` is a decision variable too but it is using nodes (not tuple values) representing if the two nodes are covered by the same trip or not.

How can I write this constraint?

Note:
When I run it using this constraint, it uses only same arc tuples

```
   forall(i,j in Setlocations :  i < j && i!=j )

   forall( g in Graph : g.o==j && g.d==i ) 

   forall(m in Graph : m.o==j && m.d==i) 
    x[g] + x[m]  <= z[i][j] ;
```

Comment: Welcome to OR SE. You wrote a "z" in your constraint. Is that a misprint (should it be "y")? Also, it would help if you edited the question to show the OPL code you use to declare the variables x and y (or z, whichever is correct).

Answer (score 1):

in [How to with OPL](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-opl-alex-fleischer/) I shared a few TSP starting points.

TSP with remove circuits is an easy one.

.mod

```
 // Cities
int     n       = ...;
range   Cities  = 1..n;

// Edges -- sparse set
tuple       edge        {int i; int j;}
setof(edge) Edges       = {<i,j> | ordered i,j in Cities};
int         dist[Edges] = ...;

// Decision variables
dvar boolean x[Edges];

 {int} nodes={i.i | i in Edges} union {i.j | i in Edges};

range r=1..-2+ftoi(pow(2,card(nodes)));


{int} nodes2 [k in r] = {i | i in nodes: ((k div (ftoi(pow(2,(ord(nodes,i))))) mod 2) == 1)};

 

 

/*****************************************************************************
 *
 * MODEL
 *
 *****************************************************************************/

// Objective
minimize sum (<i,j> in Edges) dist[<i,j>]*x[<i,j>];
subject to {
   
   // Each city is linked with two other cities
   forall (j in Cities)
        sum (<i,j> in Edges) x[<i,j>] + sum (<j,k> in Edges) x[<j,k>] == 2;
        
   // Subtour elimination constraints.
 
   
forall(k in r)  // all subsets but empty and all
    sum(e in Edges:(e.i in nodes2[k]) && (e.j in nodes2[k])) x[e]<=card(nodes2[k])-1;  

 }  
 
 
 setof(edge) solEdges       ={e | e in Edges : x[e]==1};
 execute
 {
   writeln(solEdges);
 }
```